# Dynamically showing a text box created in another class, on a win form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, textbox

My intension is to create a dynamic textbox in Form1. I have a Class 'Form1' and a Class 'SplBox'. I have declared a dynamic textbox in class 'SplBox' & passed a string to it. All I want is to call this dynamic textbox in class 'Form1' & display it in Form1 main form. In my above code a new form is getting opened up & then in this new form the dynamic textbox is shown - which I do not want

```
namespace TxtClassRun
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SplBox s1 = new SplBox();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // show the dynamic text box in Form1 
            s1.settxtbox();
            s1.Show(); // opening another window. I want it to be in "Form1"           
        }
    }

    //New Class
    public partial class SplBox : Form
    {
        //Global declarations 
        TextBox t2 = new TextBox();

        public void settxtbox()
        {
            t2.Text = "Hello World";
            Controls.Add(t2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set attributes like size, location. Here is a link to get you started: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319266/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-windows-forms-at-run-time-by-using-visual-c

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. The `SplBox` class IS a `FORM` class, therefore will simply display a new form when the button is clicked in `Form1`. Do you want to simply add a `TextBox` to `Form1` or keep the new `Form2` inside `Form1`?

Comment: Why do you create a control on one form but want to show it on another form? doens't make sense to me.

Comment: Hi JohnG, My intension is to create a dynamic textbox in Form1. I have a Class 'Form1' and a Class 'SplBox'. I have declared a dynamic textbox in class 'SplBox' & pass a string to it. All I want is to call this dynamic textbox in class 'Form1' & display it in Form1 main form. In my above code a new form is getting opened up & then in this new form the dynamic textbox is shown - which I do not want. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public partial class SplBox : Form
{
     //Global declarations 
     TextBox t2 = new TextBox();
     private Form TempOwnerForm;
     public SplBox(Form TempOwnerForm) {
         this.TempOwnerForm = TempOwnerForm;
     }
     public Form OwnerForm { get { return TempOwnerForm; } set { this.TempOwnerForm = value; } }

     public void settxtbox()
     {  
         t2.Text = "Hello World";
         TempOwnerForm.Controls.Add(t2);
     }
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Hi, thnx for your reply. But it is reporting an error.  "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'TempOwnerForm' of 'SplBox.SplBox(Form)' ". Is there any mistake I have done ?

Comment: Call like this; SplBox frm = new SplBox(this); @Bobx

Comment: when I call SplBox frm= new SplBox(this) in "public partial class Form1 : Form" it is still showing an error 'keyword this not available in current context';@Berkey

Comment: Update your question with that error put your code too please. @Bobx

Comment: My intension is to create a dynamic textbox in Form1. I have a Class 'Form1' and a Class 'SplBox'. I have declared a dynamic textbox in class 'SplBox' & pass a string to it. All I want is to call this dynamic textbox in class 'Form1' & display it in Form1 main form. In my above code a new form is getting opened up & then in this new form the dynamic textbox is shown - which I do not want.@Berkay

Comment: Thats what the solution does actually. You are calling wrong only. @Bobx

Comment: I do not understand. Can you elaborate please - where I am doing the mistake. @Berkay

Comment: You can't give this outside the scope. Create instance inside form_load. Thats why you got keyword error. @Bobx

Comment: Thanks @Berkay. It's working now. The following changes I made in 'public partial class Form1 : Form' - I have removed the Globally declared object of 'SplBox '. Instead I declared this object inside the click button event as : 'SplBox frm = new SplBox(this);' - as advised by you. Then removed 'frm Show()' - as this is actually opening another form. Instead only called function : 'frm.settxtbox();' and it's opening a dynamic textbox in the main form Form1 , which was declared in another class. Thanks for your help & sorry for all the trouble I did by asking too many questions.